# Cannot get grunt-php to launch browser and connect

Tags: gruntjs

When I use [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) in the *Gruntfile.js* for my HTML files, and the task is called, the browser launches and connects with LiveReload without issue.

I am now trying to do the same with PHP files so I am using [grunt-php](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php). The author states that grunt-php is *"pretty much a drop-in replacement for grunt-contrib-connect"*.

I have copied the options for grunt-contrib-connect to the grunt-php task, and added `keepalive` and `open`, but the browser does not get launched and no connection is made. The terminal however shows:

`Running "php:livereload" (php) task
PHP 5.4.17 Development Server started at Mon Nov 11 15:56:04 2013
Listening on http://localhost:9000
Document root is /Users/fisu/Sites/generator-site-playground/dev`

My task looks like:

```
php: {
    options: {
        keepalive: true,
        open: true,
        port: 9000,
        livereload: 35729,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        base: 'dev'
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            open: 'http://localhost:9000',
            base: 'dev'
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried different hostnames, but still the browser will not launch and connect. Am I missing an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just you. The problem seems to be with this method: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php/blob/master/tasks/php.js#L51-L59 - open() never seems to get called because it's waiting for a HTTP 200 which it won't get unless a browser hits the server and requests something. At least that seems to be the case on my machine, I don't know how well tested that method is or anything. A temporary fix could be to move that call out of that method; go into the `node_modules/grunt-php/tasks/` directory and edit the file like so:

```
(l49) // check when the server is ready. tried doing it by listening
      // to the child process `data` event, but it's not triggered...
      checkServer('http://' + host, function () {
          if (!this.flags.keepalive && !options.keepalive) {
              cb();
          }
      }.bind(this));
      // open the browser straight away
      if (options.open) {
          open('http://' + host);
      }
```

I've also filed an issue. https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php/issues/14

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for looking into that and bringing it to Sindre's attention.